# Persistent Data while Logged In

Tags: macos, cocoa, logging, nsuserdefaults

I am newbie developer in mac development. What I need to do is create an authentication dialog when the user clicks the Print button in any application.

I need to store the username and password for 1 hour (to avoid authentication all the time) but this should be deleted when the user logs out from the machine.

What I am thinking is to use NSUserDefaults to store the data, and create a logout hook to delete this data. Is this the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1). It sounds like your app fits the "Simple, Self-Restricted Application" model described in the guide.

When you create your authorization right, use the `timeout` attribute to set the length of time that the user's credentials will be cached.